# Adobe Flash Player error #2000

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have the following code:

```
//Importorting classes
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;

//Variabile declaration
var source:*; //variabile adresaressing to the source
var loader:Loader;
var loaderIndex:Number = 1; //variabile which remembers the value of the shown image.

function loadIt()
      {
         // Loading image
         loader = new Loader();
      loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onLoadingProgress); 
         loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT,initHandler); 
         addChild(loader); //functia adauga pe scena imaginea incarcata
         imagine_stepper.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,changeHandler);

         // Loading the first image...
         loadImage();//lanseaza procesul de incarcare al primei imagini
      }

          function initHandler(event:Event):void
      {
         source = loader.content;
         source.alpha = 0;
         source.x = zonaAfisare_mc.x;
         source.y = zonaAfisare_mc.y;

         addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);
      }
         function onLoadingProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void{
         var percentage:Number=(evt.bytesLoaded/evt.bytesTotal)*100;
         var total_percentage:Number=Math.floor(percentage);
         loaded.text=total_percentage.toString()+" %";
         loaded_bar.setProgress(total_percentage,100);
      }
         function changeHandler(event:Event):void
      {
         loaderIndex = imagine_stepper.value;
         loadImage();
      }
         function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
      {
         if( source.alpha < 1 ){
            source.alpha += .1;
         }else{
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);
         }
      }

      // Returning the file name path: /"imagine"+value of the variable loaderIndex +file extension
      function getPath():String
      {
         return ("images/image"+loaderIndex+".jpg");
      }
         function loadImage():void
      {
         loader.load(new URLRequest(getPath()));
      }
loadIt();
```

It gives me error #2000. yesterday it worked, now I have this error, without changing anything: no path,no photos.
What should I do?

I understand that: It looks like this line might be the cause:
loader.load(new URLRequest(getPath()));

break that up into two or three lines.

Can someone type me the correct code pls?

Comment: it might be helpful to change the Italian / Spanish / whatever language those comments are to English, so people looking at this code will have a better context of what might be going on.

Comment: good!  I just +1'd your question (thanks for translating).  Hopefully your question will get some attention from people who know the answer.

Comment: Hi first you should verify if images are correctly named (especially extension). Then you could add IOerror listener to the contentLoaderInfo and log the error in callback function.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? I am very noob at this...

Comment: ok first check is simple -> Have you images correctly named image1.jpg, image2.jpg,... in your folder "images/" ? So is the method getPath() returning the good path ? you can also check (with a simple "trace" instruction) that loaderIndex has always a correct value. Tell me if this part is ok

Comment: yes, path 100% correct... did checked